# No Class Def Found Error (android)

Tags: android

I am developing an application and I can start my Launcher activity which has two buttons. When any of these buttons is clicked a new activity should be opened. However, then a runtime error occurs.

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Intro extends Activity {

    Button searchBut, fbButton;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppSettings.loadLogin(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.intro);
        if (AppSettings.logged) {
            Intent a = new Intent(Intro.this, AllChallengesPager.class);
            a.putExtra("logging", "0");
            startActivity(a);
        }
        searchBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        searchBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(Intro.this, DetailedChallenge.class);
                a.putExtra("logging", "0");
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
        fbButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbBut);
        fbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent a = new Intent(Intro.this, AllChallengesPager.class);
                a.putExtra("logging", "1");
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
        AppSettings.loadLogin(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

---

```
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at com.example.challengeZygio.DetailedChallenge.onCreate(DetailedChallenge.java:216)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-07 11:26:07.776: E/AndroidRuntime(13305):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**- All my jar libraries are placed in libs folder
 - I have cleaned the project and restarted Eclipse for several times
 - I am using Eclipse Juno with all the newest updates**

Comment: How are you including the Android Asynchronous Http Client? Is it a Jar in the libs folder, do you use it as a library project or have you copied the source to your own source folder?

Comment: isn't your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Right click your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export`

After reaching here, libraries what you have used, "select" those libraries and move them to top of list. i.e suppose you have used "xyz.jar" file then following will be your sequence.

[x] xyz.jar
[x] Android x.x
[x] Android Dependencies
....

Save changes and rebuild your project after cleaning it.

Answer (score 1):

I had also got stuck with this problem,there can be several reasons for class not found may be your activity is not added in the Manifest,imported library is not properly added into the project as mentioned above.Another reason  can be a jar mismatch.In my case it was jar mismatch my project lib  contained  android-support.jar and my imported appcompat v7 had another version.so i simply deleted  android-support.jar  in libs of my project and problem  was  solved.

Answer (score 0):

RightClick on Project.
Go to BuildPath -> Configure Build path -> Order and Export -> select all libraries u have used -> Click ok -> Clean project

Answer (score 0):

I had also suffered the same problem. Later I got to know that adding library jar by Properties>JavaBuildPath>Library/Project is not added to the apk after build in eclipse. Instead of this, copy and paste .jar library directly to the lib folder directly and refreshing project works for me.