# error:no class definition found error. javax/mail/part

Tags: java, error-handling

I am trying to run a file but it shows this error...I have include mail.jar in class path then what could be the reason of error?

```
error:no class definition found error. javax/mail/part
```

I haven't included the code as its a big code and I don't know which part to post..

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your Build Path.

> Right click your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order &
>   Export
>
> After reaching here, libraries what you have used, "select" those
>   libraries and move them to top of list. i.e suppose you have used
>   "xyz.jar" file then following will be your sequence.
>
> [x] xyz.jar 
>   [x] someother.jar
>
> Save changes and rebuild your project after cleaning it.

taken from [No Class Def Found Error (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980159/no-class-def-found-error-android)